# Is there a way to implement access decision manager on HTTP listener connector on the fly without creating a class or component?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I was wondering if there is way to apply access decision manager on HTTP listener connector path directly rather than a component in mule studio?
Something like **localhost:8081/GetEmployee=ROLE_ADMIN**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use filter to achieve this. Put filter on query parameter.

Please refer this for more details.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.4/using-filters

HTH.